# moodle plugin installing issue?

Tags: plugins, moodle

I am unable to install the following question types with my moodle
1. Drag and drop into text (qtype_ddwtos)
2. Drag and drop matching (qtype_ddmatch)

I am using I am using Moodle 2.5.4 (Build: 20140113), php 5.4.7, MySQL 5.5.27, Apache 2.4.3, XAMPP server version 1.8.1

I have downloaded the plugins and unzip it then placed in the moodle->question->type. After that if I click the notifications link it is showing only blank page. Please advise me how to go further and how to resolve this issue and make use of those plugins.

Comment: Please turn on Debugging http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging and then share the error message you get.

Answer (score 2):

the idea is to give the 755 permission to the "ddmatch" and "ddwtos" folders.

1- copy the two folder to moodle->question->type (as you did)

2- cd to this this directory:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/moodle/question/type
```

3- and change the permission of the two folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ddwtos ddmatch
```

it worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out 2.5.4 and downloaded the plugins you mentioned - making sure they were both 2.5 versions - and extracted them into /question/type

https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=qtype_ddmatch

https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=qtype_ddwtos

Then went to notifications, they both require other plugins

[image: question types plugins required]

qtype_match doesn't exist unfortunately

https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=qtype_match

However gapselect does, so I downloaded that one too

https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=qtype_gapselect

Then ran the upgrade and no errors were shown.

Is this on linux? Its possible that the extracted files haven't got the correct permissions - check the ownership of the folders : http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/Security_recommendations#Running_Moodle_on_a_dedicated_server

I would also double check that the files have been unzipped into the correct folder - so you should have /question/type/ddmatch, /question/type/ddwtos and /question/type/gapselect

If all that is okay then, like davosmith says, if you can switch on debugging and paste the error here. If you can't get into the system then edit /config.php and add these 2 lines after $CFG = new stdClass();

```
$CFG->debug = 32767;
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;
```

Then try going to notifications again and see what the error is /admin/index.php

Comment: I have no idea what's going on with the crazy rollbacks, but I've put this on lock down for an hour.